# How to uncompress zlib data in UNIX?

Tags: compression, gzip

I have created zlib-compressed data in Python, like this:

```
import zlib
s = '...'
z = zlib.compress(s)
with open('/tmp/data', 'w') as f:
    f.write(z)
```

(or one-liner in shell: `echo -n '...' | python2 -c 'import sys,zlib; sys.stdout.write(zlib.compress(sys.stdin.read()))' > /tmp/data`)

Now, I want to uncompress the data in shell. Neither `zcat` nor `uncompress` work:

```
$ cat /tmp/data | gzip -d -
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

$ zcat /tmp/data 
gzip: /tmp/data.gz: not in gzip format

$ cat /tmp/data | uncompress -
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
```

It seems that I have created gzip-like file, but without any headers. Unfortunately I don't see any option to uncompress such raw data in gzip man page, and the zlib package does not contain any executable utility.

Is there a utility to uncompress raw zlib data?

Comment: There are many additional answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178566/deflate-command-line-tool

Answer (score 211, accepted):

It is also possible to decompress it using standard [shell-script](/questions/tagged/shell-script) + [gzip](/questions/tagged/gzip), if you don't have, or want to use [openssl](/questions/tagged/openssl) or other tools.
The trick is to prepend the [gzip magic number and compress method](https://web.archive.org/web/20200220015003/http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gzip.html) to the actual data from `zlib.compress`:

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - /tmp/data |gzip -dc >/tmp/out
```

Edits:
@d0sboots commented: For RAW Deflate data, you need to add 2 more null bytes: 
 → `"\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"`

[This Q on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050260/what-does-a-zlib-header-look-like) gives more information about this approach. An answer there suggests that there is also an 8 byte footer.

Users @Vitali-Kushner and @mark-bessey reported success even with truncated files, so a gzip footer does not seem strictly required.

@tobias-kienzler suggested this function for the [bashrc](/questions/tagged/bashrc):
`zlibd() (printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - "$@" | gzip -dc)`

Comment: gzip doesn't work, but zlib-flate does (pdf page content stream).

Comment: inverse operation: `cat input.txt | gzip -c | tail -c +9 >compressed.gzbody` to remove the first 8 bytes

Comment: Small detail about shell functions: the suggested function uses parenthesis as block delimiter, which causes the unnecessary creation of a subshell. Using curly braces: `zlibd() { printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - "$@" | gzip -dc; }`

Comment: TFW you find a great answer, see *yourself* quoted in the answer, but can't find the comment that you were quoted from anywhere...

Answer (score 157):

```
zlib-flate -uncompress < IN_FILE > OUT_FILE
```

I tried this and it worked for me.

`zlib-flate` can be found in package `qpdf` (in Debian Squeeze, Fedora 23, and brew on MacOS according to comments in other answers)

*(Thanks to user @tino who provided this as a comment below the OpenSSL answer. Made into propper answer for easy access.)*

Comment: In contrast to the other answers, this one works on OS X.

Comment: @polym, how did you get `zlib-flate` *installed* on macOS?  I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: @Wildcard sorry for the late response. I think it came with the `qpdf` package that I've installed with `brew` as mentioned in the [comment above](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/how-to-uncompress-zlib-data-in-unix/240060#comment67353_22837) - or look at the last sentence of this answer :). Also, `qpdf` is really cool, so have a look at it too if you have time!

Comment: brew install qpdf, then the command listed above :-) thank you!

Comment: This is really useful if you're learning how git objects are stored, using this instead of `git cat-file -p` works fine!

Comment: @Rodrirokr the problem of `cat-file -p` is that it *pretty prints* the content, so it can give a completely false impression of the contents e.g. an on-disk tree object is very different than what `cat-file` shows.

Answer (score 93):

I have found a solution (one of the possible ones), it's using **openssl**:

```
$ openssl zlib -d < /tmp/data
```

or

```
$ openssl zlib -d -in /tmp/data
```

*NOTE: zlib functionality is apparently available in recent openssl versions >=1.0.0 (OpenSSL has to be configured/built with zlib or zlib-dynamic option, the latter is default)

Comment: On Debian Squeeze (which has OpenSSL 0.9.8) there is `zlib-flate` in the `qpdf` package.  It can be used like `zlib-flate -uncompress < FILE`.

Comment: zlib got removed from the latest versions of OpenSSL so this tip is is very helpful @Tino

Comment: Thanks. This solution provides a better experience in decompressing short input files than the answer using "gzip" ("openssl" decompressed as much as it could while "gzip"  aborted printing "unexpected end of file").

Comment: @Tino this should be a separate answer

Comment: @Tino, it is also available via the package qpdf on Fedora 23. Alexandr Kurilin, zlib is still available in 1.0.2d-fips.

Comment: there another openssl syntax that does the same, using openssl enc:

$openssl enc -z -none -d < /tmp/data

Answer (score 73):

I recommend [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/) from [Mark Adler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Adler), co-author of the zlib compression library.  Execute `pigz` to see the available flags.

You will notice:

`-z --zlib    Compress to zlib (.zz) instead of gzip format.`

You can uncompress using the `-d` flag:

`-d --decompress --uncompress    Decompress the compressed input.`

Assuming a file named 'test':

- `pigz -z test`          - creates a zlib compressed file named test.zz
- `pigz -d -z test.zz`    - converts test.zz to the decompressed test file

On OSX you can execute `brew install pigz`

Comment: Good find! It looks like it can detect zlib files by itself, so `unpigz test.zz` will work as well.

Comment: did not decompress my data.

Comment: @cybernard perhaps you don't have a zlib file.  check with:
`$>file hello.txt.zz` 
`hello.txt.zz: zlib compressed data`

Comment: Worked well with partial files too.

Comment: Playing around with git objects, the following will work: `unpigz -z < FILE`

Answer (score 12):

On macOS, which is a full POSIX compliant UNIX (formally certified!), `OpenSSL` has no `zlib` support, there is no `zlib-flate` either and while the first solution works as well as all the Python solutions, the first solution requires the ZIP data to be in a file and all the other solutions force you to create a Python script.

Here's a Perl based solution that can be used as a command line one-liner, gets its input via STDIN pipe and that works out of the box with a freshly installed macOS:

```bash
cat file.compressed | perl -e 'use Compress::Raw::Zlib;my $d=new Compress::Raw::Zlib::Inflate();my $o;undef $/;$d->inflate(<>,$o);print $o;'
```

Nicer formatted, the Perl script looks like this:

```perl
use Compress::Raw::Zlib;
my $decompressor = new Compress::Raw::Zlib::Inflate();
my $output;
undef $/;
$decompressor->inflate(<>, $output);
print $output;
```

---

Optimized version from Marco d'Itri (see comments):

```bash
cat file.compressed | perl -MCompress::Zlib -E 'undef $/;print uncompress(<>)'
```

Comment: A shorter solution is: perl -MCompress::Zlib -E 'undef $/;print uncompress(<>)'

Answer (score 11):

[`zlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) implements the compression used by gzip, but not the file format. Instead, you should use the [`gzip` module](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html), which itself uses `zlib`.

```
import gzip
s = '...'
with gzip.open('/tmp/data', 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: ok, but my situation is that i have tens/hundreds thousands of those files created, so.. :)

Comment: so... your files are incomplete. Perhaps you'll have to uncompress them with `zlib` and recompress them with `gzip`, if you don't still have the original data.

Comment: @mykhal, why did you create ten/hundred thousands of files before checking that you could actually uncompress them?

Comment: harpyon, i can uncompress them, i just wonder which less or more common urility or zgip settings can be used for that, if i don't want to do it in python again

Answer (score 7):

The example program `zpipe.c` [found here](https://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c) by Mark Adler himself (comes with the source distribution of the zlib library) is very useful for these scenarios with raw zlib data. Compile with `cc -o zpipe zpipe.c -lz` and to decompress: `zpipe -d < raw.zlib > decompressed`. It can also do the compression without the `-d` flag.

Answer (score 6):

This might do it:

```
import glob
import zlib
import sys

for filename in sys.argv:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as compressed:
        with open(filename + '-decompressed', 'wb') as expanded:
            data = zlib.decompress(compressed.read())
            expanded.write(data)
```

Then run it like this:

```
$ python expander.py data/*
```

Comment: thanks, i know about `zlib.decompress`. probably i'd use some walk function. i'm not sure if shell would handle my huge amount of files with glob wildcard :)

Comment: The file that is created by expanded still checks out as "zlib compressed data" for me, using the shell `file` command? How is that?

Comment: nope doesn't work for me even with the fake header.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to compress with zlib:

```
openssl enc -z -none -e < /file/to/deflate
```

And this to deflate:

```
openssl enc -z -none -d < /file/to/deflate
```

Comment: Gives `unknown option '-z'` on Ubuntu 16.04 and `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Comment: same error on Mac

Answer (score 2):

During development of eIDAS related code, i've came up with bash script, that decodes SSO (SingleSignOn) SAMLRequest param, which is usually encoded by base64 and raw-deflate (php gzdeflate)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# file decode_saml_request.sh

urldecode() { : "${*//+/ }"; echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"; }

if [[ $contents == *"SAMLRequest" ]]; then
  # extract param SAMLRequest from URL, strip all following params
  contents=$(cat ${1} | awk -F 'SAMLRequest=' '{print $2}' | awk -F '&' '{print $1}')
else
  # work with raw base64 encoded string
  contents=$(cat ${1})
fi

# add gzip raw-deflate header bytes and gunzip (`gzip -dc` can be replaced by `gunzip`)
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - <(echo `urldecode $contents` | base64 -d) | gzip -dc
```

You can use it like

```bsh
> decode_saml_request.sh /path/to/file_with_sso_url
# or
> echo "y00tLk5MT1VISSxJBAA%3D" | decode_saml_request.sh
```

Script is published also as gist here: https://gist.github.com/smarek/77dacb9703ac8b715b5eced5314d5085 so i may not maintain this answer but I will maintain the source gist

Answer (score 2):

I have an addition to @Alex Stragies conversion for those who need a proper header and footer (an actual conversion from zlib to gzip).

It would probably be easier to use one of the above methods, however if the reader has a case like mine which requires conversion of zlib to gzip without decompression and recompression, this is the way to do it.

According to RFC1950/1952, A zlib file can only have a single stream or member. This is different from gzip in that:

> A gzip file consists of a series of "members" (compressed data
> sets). ...  The members simply appear one after another in the file,
> with no additional information before, between, or after them.

This means that while a single zlib file can always be converted to a single gzip file, the converse is not strictly true. Something to keep in mind.

zlib has both a header (2 bytes) and a footer (4 bytes) which must be removed from the data so that the gzip header and footer can be appended. One way of doing that is as follows:

```
# Remove zlib 4 byte footer
trunc_size=$(ls -l infile.z | awk '{print $5 - 4}')
truncate -s $trunc_size infile.z


# Remove zlib 2 byte header
dd bs=1M iflag=skip_bytes skip=2 if=infile.z of=tmp1.z
```

Now we have just raw data and may append the gzip header (from @Alex Stragies)

```
printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" | cat - tmp1.z > tmp2.z
```

The gzip footer is 8 bytes long. It consists the CRC32 of the uncompressed file, plus the size of the file uncompressed mod 2^32, both in big endian format. If you don't know these but have means of getting an uncompressed file:

```
generate_crcbig() {
    crc=$(crc32 $uncompressedfile)
    crcbig=$(echo "\x${crc:6:2}\x${crc:4:2}\x${crc:2:2}\x${crc:0:2}")
}

generate_lbig () {
    leng=$(ls -l $uncompressedfile | awk '{print $5}')
    lmod=$(expr $leng % 4294967296) # mod 2^32
    lhex=$(printf "%x\n" $lmod)
    lbig=$(echo "\x${lhex:6:2}\x${lhex:4:2}\x${lhex:2:2}\x${lhex:0:2}")
}
```

And then the footer may be appended as such:

```
printf $crcbig$lbig | cat tmp3.z - > outfile.gz
```

Now you have a file which is in the gzip format! It can be verified with `gzip -t outfile.gz` and uncompressed with any application complying with gzip specifications.

Answer (score 2):

I get it that author doesn't want to use Python but I believe that Python3 1-liner is natural choice for most Linux users, so let it be here:

`python3 -c 'import sys,zlib; sys.stdout.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.buffer.read()).decode())' < $COMPRESSED_FILE_PATH`

Comment: The `.decode()` here makes this useless for binary data, unfortunately

Comment: Another `.buffer` fixes that: `python3 -c 'import sys,zlib; sys.stdout.buffer.write(zlib.decompress(sys.stdin.buffer.read()))'`

Answer (score 0):

The simple inflate program pufftest.c found in contrib/puff of [zlib packet](https://zlib.net) by Mark Adler himself can handle raw zlib data whithout header bytes and Adler32 checksum. Compile with `cc -o pufftest puff.c pufftest.c` and to inflate: `pufftest < raw.zlib > decompressed`. Note, it can't deflate.

Answer (score -5):

```
zcat -f infile > outfile
```

works for me on fedora25

Comment: `zcat` only works with files in the gzip format.