# How to run zlib from terminal on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, terminal, compression

I've installed `zlib1g` but still `zlib` isn't available from the terminal. How can I find the executable to run it? Or is there an easier way I'm overlooking?

The reason for this is that I want to compress a file using zlib to match an existing implementation from a third-party application.

Comment: What do you mean "run zlib"? It's a library, you can call functions from that library in code you write. It's not a command to be executed.

Comment: zlib doesnt provide a command line tool.  you can write one yourself, or install qpdf which provides a `zlib-flate` command that can compress and decomress zlib streams.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uncompress zlib data in UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22834/how-to-uncompress-zlib-data-in-unix)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across `pigz` which allows for just this via `pigz -z [input_file_name]` to output a compressed file.